# Call center Asterisk Dial extension analog phone

Tags: asterisk

I have a question hoping someone can explain in detail, I have integrated IVR system with Asterisk, everything is good, now the part I have to do is call center, press <kbd>1</kbd> for this, press <kbd>0</kbd> to talk to support, now this line which user calls to hear IVR menu is coming from a PBX, and PBX also has 5 other lines which are attached to analog phones each having its extension, how do I dial/transfer call to those extensions to the call center agents? Or do I have the wrong approach?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this. You'll want to read up on Asterisk queues and on how to build menus.

Essentially, you use your DAHDI config to direct your incoming call lines to your Auto Attendant/ IVR.  Your queue agents are the other lines.  The Asterisk queue system will handle the "automatic call routing" ACR work of getting the call from the queue to the right agent.

Further reading: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Building+Queues
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Creating+a+Simple+IVR+Menu